# Is it possible to obtain objects from distributed cache in a Hadoop Partitioner?

Tags: caching, hadoop, distributed-cache

Hadoop's Distributed Cache lets the developer add small files to the MR context which can be used to obtain additional information during Map or Reduce phases. However, I did not find a way to access this cache in a `Partitioner`. I need the contents of a small file (the output of an earlier MR job) in a custom `Partitioner` to determine how the keys are sent to the reducers.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any useful documentation on this, and my only idea is currently a somewhat "hackish" approach, which involves serializing the contents of the file to a Base64 string and putting it into the `Configuration`. `Configuration`s can be used in a partitioner by letting it implement `Configurable`. While the file is small enough for this approach (around 50KB) I suppose the distributed cache is better suited for this.

**EDIT:**
I found another approach which I consider slightly better. Since the file I need to access in the partitioner is on HDFS, I put its fully-qualified `URI` into the `Configuration`. In my `Partitioner`'s `setConf` method I can then re-create the Path via `new Path(new URI(conf.get("some.file.key")))` and read it with the help of the `Configuration`. Still hackish though...

Comment: Please share a working example code of this.